# strange exception in keyboard library << python

Tags: python, keyboard

I want to wait until the button 'q' is pressed

this is my code:

```
import keyboard
while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            print('q is pressed')
            break #finishing the loop
```

and this is the exception i got:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 134, in listen
    _os_keyboard.listen(self.queue, _key_table.is_allowed)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_winkeyboard.py", line 423, in listen
    keyboard_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboard_callback, NULL, NULL)
ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected CFunctionType instance instead of CFunctionType
```

what is the problem?

Comment: It's possible the module you've installed doesn't play nice with Windows.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ According to its pypi page, this one *should*: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard

Comment: I'm getting a different error: `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. It's not the first time that module has done some weird things. Hard to tell if your installation is broken or if the module itself is broken (once again).

Comment: Since this is very specific to this module, it might be more suitable as an issue in its github page https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Comment: @Rawing is there a better module to work with?

Comment: @LiorSwisa I don't know any, unfortunately. But in my experience the author of that module responds to bug reports very quickly, so it's not a huge problem. Last time I reported a bug, it got fixed within 2 hours.

Comment: tnx everyone i asked in its github page

Comment: here's another option, pynput: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput